# Using Parameters in yamlFile of kubernetes agent in jenkins decorative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, jenkins-kubernetes

I have a shared yaml file for multiple pipelines and I would like to parameterize the tag of one of the images in the yaml file.

What would be the simplest way to do this? At the moment I am maintaining multiple `KubernetesPods.yaml`, such as `KubernetesPods-1.5.0.yaml` and interpolating the parameter into the name ( `yamlFile "KubernetesPods-${params.AGENT_POD_SPEC}.yaml"`), but this does not scale well.

Can I get parameters into the yaml without having to have the yaml written out in every pipeline?

Example pipeline:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      yamlFile 'KubernetesPods.yaml'
    }
  }
  parameters {
    choice(
      name: 'AGENT_POD_SPEC',
      choices: ['1.5.0','1.3.0','1.2.0','1.4.0'],
      description: 'Agent pod configuration'
    )
  }
}
```

Example KubernetesPods.yaml:

```
kind: Pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: example-image
    image: example/image:<IMAGE-TAG-I-WANT-TO-PARAMETERIZE>
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    command:
    - cat
```

Comment: You could load the manifest in as a Map from the YAML, modify the Map, and then write it back out to YAML. However, it would be easier to input the value of the JP parameter as a value via something like Helm.

Comment: Whereabouts would I load in the yaml and edit it? In the agent block?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `yaml` instead of `yamlFile`

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      yaml """
kind: Pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: example-image
    image: example/image:${params.AGENT_POD_SPEC}
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    command:
    - cat
"""
    }
  }
  parameters {
    choice(
      name: 'AGENT_POD_SPEC',
      choices: ['1.5.0','1.3.0','1.2.0','1.4.0'],
      description: 'Agent pod configuration'
    )
  }
}
```